# PullToRefreshAttacher NullPointerException on Actionbar tab switch

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have an app that uses ActionBar.Tab and implements the pulltorefresh library from Chris Banes.
In one tab I have multiple fragments (like a navigation).

If in a tab I am in the parent fragment, I can switch tabs without issues.
However, if in a tab I am in a child fragment, I get a NullPointerException when changing tabs.

The exception is **(Edited to include the full exception)**:

```
06-13 12:38:02.291: D/AndroidRuntime(22892): Shutting down VM
06-13 12:38:02.291: W/dalvikvm(22892): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4165fd40)
06-13 12:38:02.296: E/AndroidRuntime(22892): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 12:38:02.296: E/AndroidRuntime(22892): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 22892
06-13 12:38:02.296: E/AndroidRuntime(22892): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 12:38:02.296: E/AndroidRuntime(22892):    at uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshAttacher.addHeaderViewToActivity(PullToRefreshAttacher.java:594)
06-13 12:38:02.296: E/AndroidRuntime(22892):    at uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshAttacher$2.run(PullToRefreshAttacher.java:128)
06-13 12:38:02.296: E/AndroidRuntime(22892):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-13 12:38:02.296: E/AndroidRuntime(22892):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-13 12:38:02.296: E/AndroidRuntime(22892):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-13 12:38:02.296: E/AndroidRuntime(22892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
06-13 12:38:02.296: E/AndroidRuntime(22892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 12:38:02.296: E/AndroidRuntime(22892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-13 12:38:02.296: E/AndroidRuntime(22892):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-13 12:38:02.296: E/AndroidRuntime(22892):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-13 12:38:02.296: E/AndroidRuntime(22892):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using Chris' code as library in my project.
Also, here's how I'm handling the switch of tabs in my "MainFragment" (which holds the ActionBar.Tab and all fragments)
**ADDED IT BELOW WITH MONDAY'S UPDATE**

**Update:**
Last line of code called before the exception gets invoked:
            mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(mRect);
This line is from class "PullToRefreshAttacher.class" from the pulltorefresh.jar library.
Here's the entire method where this class is:

```
protected void addHeaderViewToActivity(View headerView) {
    // Get the Display Rect of the Decor View
    mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(mRect);

    // Honour the requested layout params
    int width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams requestedLp = headerView.getLayoutParams();
    if (requestedLp != null) {
        width = requestedLp.width;
        height = requestedLp.height;
    }

    // Create LayoutParams for adding the View as a panel
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(width, height,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    wlp.x = 0;
    wlp.y = mRect.top;
    wlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

    // Workaround for Issue #182
    headerView.setTag(wlp);
    mActivity.getWindowManager().addView(headerView, wlp);
}
```

**Update:
Per request of Ultimo_m, here are my classes:**

Class "MainFragmentActivity" holds all fragments

```
public class MainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
private final String TAG_FRAGMENT_LIST = “list";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_fragment);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setTitle(getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().labelRes);  

    ActionBar.Tab tab_list = actionBar.newTab().setText(“List”);
    tab_jobList.setIcon(R.drawable.text_list_white);

    Fragment fragmentList = new ListLV();

    tab_list.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragmentList, TAG_FRAGMENT_LIST));

    actionBar.addTab(tab_jobList);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Log.d("length out", "" + fm.getBackStackEntryCount());

    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 2) 
    {
        //do nothing since i'm on other fragments
    } 
    else 
    {
        // im are in my activity two or one so pop the fragment
        fm.popBackStack();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu. This adds items to the action bar if it is present
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.global_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
    private Fragment fragment;
    private String mTag;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment, String tag)
    {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        mTag = tag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack();

        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
}   
}//end class MainFragmentActivity
```

Class ListLV is the "parent class" inside the MainFragmentActivity class

```
public class ListLV extends ListFragment implements ResultsListener
{
Context context;
ArrayList<Job> arrayOfJobs;
DatabaseHandler db;
private PullToRefreshLayout pullToRefreshLayout;
SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    context = inflater.getContext();
    db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    arrayOfJobs = db.getAllJobs();

    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.myapp”, 0);

    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(context, arrayOfJobs);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); 
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);          

    // This is the View which is created by ListFragment
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;

    // We need to create a PullToRefreshLayout manually
    pullToRefreshLayout = new PullToRefreshLayout(viewGroup.getContext());

    // We can now setup the PullToRefreshLayout
    ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity())
    .insertLayoutInto(viewGroup) // We need to insert the PullToRefreshLayout into the Fragment's ViewGroup
    .theseChildrenArePullable(getListView(), getListView().getEmptyView())// We need to mark the ListView and it's Empty View as pullable This is because they are not direct children of the
    // ViewGroup
    .options(Options.create()
            .refreshingText("Downloading...")
            .pullText("Pull to refresh!")
            .releaseText("Release!")
            .titleTextColor(android.R.color.black)
            .progressBarColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark)
            .headerBackgroundColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light)
            .progressBarStyle(Options.PROGRESS_BAR_STYLE_INSIDE)
            .build())
    .listener(new OnRefreshListener() { // We can now complete the setup as desired
        @Override
        public void onRefreshStarted(View view) 
        {
            System.out.println("onRefreshStarted");
            // Get data again
        }
    })
    .setup(pullToRefreshLayout);

}


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    // Create new fragment and transaction
    Fragment newFragment = new ListDetails();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // pass data between fragments
    Job job = arrayOfJobs.get(position);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("job", job);
    newFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onResultsSucceeded(String result) 
{       
    arrayOfJobs.clear();
    arrayOfJobs = db.getAllJobs();

    JobListAdapter adapter = new JobListAdapter(context, arrayOfJobs);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    Toast.makeText(context, db.getNumberOfJobs() + " jobs in SQLite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    pullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();
}
}//end class ListLV
```

Class ListDetails is the "child" inside the ListLV class

```
public class ListDetails extends Fragment
{
Job job;
Context context;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    job = (Job) arguments.getSerializable("job");
    context = inflater.getContext();

    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


    // setting values on widgets

    return view;

}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        Activity a = getActivity();
        if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
}
```

Any idea on how I can solve this issue?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you show the part of code where you get NullPointerException ?

Comment: ? what do you need, specifically?
I added the code of my tab listener, and the error that I get when switching tabs from within a tab child

Comment: Can you post your full LogCat to undertstand where error happens, because you are showing only a part of it

Comment: I just updated the question to include the entire print stack of the exception

Comment: Do you call this method from your code `addHeaderViewToActivity` ? Can you debug your code to see at which line it gives NPE ?

Comment: 1. I don't have any reference to "addHeaderViewToActivity" in my code
2. Updated the question to add the entire code of the last method (and line) being called.
Thanks

Comment: In which fragments are you setting up the PullToRefreshLayout? All of them or just one, and in which method?

Comment: 1. Currently the PullToRefreshLayout is only being used in the class that has the parent -> child class. This is setup in the parent class.
2. The PullToRefreshLayout is being setup in the onViewCreated method

Comment: Can you post your parent and child class ? Because there seems to be the problem

Comment: Hi Ultimo_m, I just added the 2 classes you requested, plus the class that holds the fragments.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you using custom tab listener (MyTabsListener) if you are doing nothing special in it?
your main fragmentActivity could implement Actionbar.Tablistener.

an example:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


    AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.
        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();


        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
        // user swipes between sections.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab.
                // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
                // Tab.
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

            // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
            for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                /* Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
                 Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
                 listener for when this tab is selected.*/
                int tabIcon = 0;
                switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    tabIcon = R.drawable.ic_tab_1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tabIcon = R.drawable.ic_tab_2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tabIcon = R.drawable.ic_tab_3;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tabIcon = R.drawable.ic_tab_4;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                actionBar.addTab(
                        actionBar.newTab()
                                .setIcon(tabIcon)
                                .setTabListener(this));
            }
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }



    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    return new ListLV();
                case 1:

                    return new Fragment_2();

                case 3:

                    return new Fragment_3();

                default:

                    return new Fragment_4();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String tabText = "";
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                tabText = "Tab 1";
                break;
            case 1:
                tabText = "Tab 2";
                break;
            case 2:
                tabText = "Tab 3";
                break;
            case 3:
                tabText = "Tab 4";
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return tabText;
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: I don't have a strong reason to do it other than that's the way I learned to do it.
Is this what's causing the crash?

Comment: probably. because for some reason on tab change listener is passing arguments when you are inside parent fragments only.
make a back up of your main file somewhere else and use the one I've put here. see if it works.

Comment: Hey I'm a bit confused. What are these 2 variables:

    AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;'

And why do you have another inner class as an Adapter class?
public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: have you worked with listview? if you want to use a custom adapter to show the list the way you want. this is the same. it is a list of tabs and for showing them the way yo want you should define a custom adapter. which in this case is called  AppSectionsPagerAdapter and mAppSectionsPagerAdapter is just an instance of it. you know when you define a class you should create a new instance of it inside a variable. then you can use that class.

Comment: and mViewPager is just a variable that holds the ViewPager class.
which you can use it to first assign a view to it which in my example it's a LinearLayout called R.id.pager or something else to put everything you want in your app inside it. then you use mViewPager to add the custom adapter we created( AppSectionsPagerAdapter) to it.
the you can assign events like setOnPageChangeListener to ViewPager

Comment: Ok so I think I've implemented most of it this way, but I have 2 errors in the Adapter.

The constructor of AppSectionsPagerAdapter gives me an error "The constructor FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined"
This is the constructor:
        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
        {
            super(fm);
        }

Comment: And the getItem also gives me an error: "The return type is incompatible with FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int)"

Here's the getItem:
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i)
        {
            switch (i) 
            {
                case 0:
                    return new ListLV();
                    break;
            }
        }

The ListLV class extends ListFragment, in case that is the problem, but I have also changed the return type to ListFragment but it doesn't compile either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55801/discussion-between-m-d-p-and-toomanyeduardos).

Comment: What is this "mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);"
What kind of layout is this?

Comment: This is somewhat the correct answer, although it required A LOT of extra modifications.
However, this answer started the correct chain reaction.

Comment: i'm glad it helped. it was a prototype like though. basic example of using ViewPager. 
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
this can be a holder for your apps contents. 
you should put it in your main activity xml like this:

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


and everything in your app will be shown inside this which fills the whole screen.

Comment: well I offered it and you helped me, so it was worth it

Comment: I suggest you use [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library. they made it really good and useful. they also have a very good examples and their source codes. good luck.